# Solr wildcard search with special character

Tags: solr

My user wants to search with special character and wildcard. Dash (-) in this case.

So if I search with 'xxx' or 'xxx\-'
I get the results containing "xxx-" and "xxx".
But I do not want "xxx", I only want results that has "xxx-". (the dash)

I tried searching with xxx-*, does not give me any results.

The schema looks like this

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: can you specifically tell what you want when you search `xxx` and `xxx-`?

Comment: What's an extra slash `/`  for in `xxx\-`?

Comment: @VishalSingh when I search with "xxx-*", I want to see results that starts with "xxx-".
meaning i do not want to see a result that starts with only "xxx". 
I want solr to consider the dash (-).

For your 2nd question, I read up in solr document that (-) is a special character and needs to be escaped hence xxx\-

Comment: what version of solr are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I achive it with following

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="field_name" stored="true" type="string"/>
```

Searching with `field_name=xxx-*` delivers me only fields starting with `xxx-`.

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding the Problem.**

> Standard Tokenizer
>
> This tokenizer splits the text field into tokens, treating
> whitespace and punctuation as delimiters and delimiter characters are discarded.

In your case `-` is the punctuation that why there are no results when you search `xxx-`.

What you can do is replace `StandardTokenizerFactory` with `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` which will split the text stream on whitespace only preserving punctuations in the tokens.

Comment: its a dynamic field I am searching into. Its called "answer_t". After I changed the above as you mentioned, reindex, restart solr, the field "answer_t" is gone.
I do not see it.

Comment: @CrimeMasterGogo can you share the schema of your dynamic fields in your post?